# Read character '-' in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm developing a C project for school, and I have to read a CSV file. My problem is that some values include spaces, and that's why I can't use `fscanf(file, "%s", string);`.

I've tried this : `fscanf(file, "%[0-9A-Za-z ,.-]", string);`, `fscanf(file, "%[0-9A-Za-z ,.\-]", string);` and `fscanf(file, "%[0-9A-Za-z ,.--]", string);` but none of these are working.

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Use `fgets()`..

Comment: Does it stop with \r?

Comment: You can't parse a CSV with `scanf` because fields can be quoted. It's not difficult to write a lexer from scratch, and that's probably what I'd do. But that said, can you provide an example string that your scanf fails to read? Maybe a minimal reproduction, including a hard-coded string to parse, and some example program that reads it?